# extendscript how do i add a code to one of my tabbed panel i have

Tags: extendscript

i have a hash code it runs direct of the extendscript how do i add it to my script on specific panel..

here is where i want this code to be added

```
var comppp = tpanel.add("tab", undefined, undefined, {name: "clrTab"}); 
comppp.text = "Comp Settings2"; 
comppp.orientation = "column"; 
comppp.alignChildren = ["fill","top"]; 
comppp.spacing = 10; 
comppp.margins = 10;
```

here is the part of the code i had to cut part of it out so i can post it here.
it has 2 same code like this starting with **eval("**
is it possible to add to my panel **comppp**

```
eval("@JSXBIN@ES@2.0@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");
```

Comment: Are you attempting to launch a script from within a script? If so, would this be done with the help of an event listener, such as a button click? 

If not are you able to give me a little description of what the hashed code is supposed to do?

Comment: the has code is longer and when i paste it full in new page in extendscript it opens a fully loaded script with ui and buttons made by other. i just want it implimented on my script. how do i maybe add this code to my script then execute it though

Comment: I think it would be a much better solution to keep the other scripts as external files and launch the script by pointing to the file instead. I can teach you how to do that if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to keep the jsxbin as a seperate file and then launch that file from within your script. No reason to unnecessarily bloat your code.

```js
var launchScriptBtn = mainTab_BtnGrp.add("button", undefined, undefined, {name: "launch_script_btn"}); 
    launchScriptBtn.text = "Launch Script"; 
    launchScriptBtn.onClick = function(){
      launchScript()
    };

function launchScript() {
  var script = new File("scriptFile.jsxbin"); // File location 
  script.open("r");
  eval(script.read());
  script.close();
}
```

Comment: for some reason, i added my patht o jsx its not opening the button remains normal nothing opens.

Comment: Is the script you are attempting to launch located within the same folder as the script you are writing? My best guess is that you have the file path incorrect. I've tested this and it's working for me.